# C# MongoDb Project with DateTime.date

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-aggregation

**Given:**

I've a mongodb collection with some data. One field is a DateTime field .

Now I want to aggregate the data for each day.

for this I created this aggregation

```
var result = collection
                .Aggregate()
                .Project(i => new {i.Key,date = i.Timestamp.Date})
                .Group(k => k.date,l => new { l.Key,count =l.Count()})
                .ToList();
```

**Problem:**

Now Mongo db is telling mit that `i.TimeStamp.Date` is not supported. I assume that it just cant translate it to a "ToDate" function.

What would be the correct way to group such data by date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was checking in cshardriver project and there is no extension like that yet, 
that means we need to use bson document to get this working.

```
var project =  BsonDocument.Parse("{Key:1, Timestamp:1,year:{$year:'$Timestamp'}, dayOfYear:{$dayOfYear:'$Timestamp'}}");

var group = BsonDocument.Parse("{_id:{year:'$year', dayOfYear:'$dayOfYear'}, count:{$sum:1}}");

var result = collection
                .Aggregate()
                .Project(project)
                .Group(group)
                .ToList();
```

We could have typed object  `Project<ournewClassrepresentingProjectShape>(project)` and then we can use typed group.

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Thx this works, I just thought I'm missing something in the fluent api

Comment: no problem jira ticket here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1700